# How to get CheckedListBox.checkedItems as a stringlist

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I am trying to get `CheckedListBox.CheckedItems` as a StringList. But I don't know how to get it. I am trying to make it as a one liner using LINQ. My insufficient experience in .Net-C# is not capable to do that. Can anybody say how to do that?

Note: I am using .Net-4.0.

Comment: You can do something like `list.CheckedItems.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToList()`, but are you sure you want to convert them to string?

Comment: @Saeed Your idea didn't work . This is the error I got "'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ".

Comment: I was wrong, I thought `CheckedItemCollection` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but implements `IEnumerable`, so it doesn't work with linq.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the values you stored in those items are strings:

```
List<string> items = chk.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

If they are of some custom type you could use that type:

```
List<SomeTypeUsedForTheItems> items = chk.CheckedItems.Cast<SomeTypeUsedForTheItems>().ToList();
```